# javascript callback question

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript which I didn't write but I need to use it ..

```
    function function1()
    ... body..
    and at the end 
    I have this
 'callback': 'getListCallback'
  }
```

What does this callback mean and `getListCallback = function(obj)` is another function, does this mean that results from function1 are returned to function getListCallback?

Tnx

Comment: rewrite the code so it is actual javascript and not pseudo code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A callback function is a function that is going to be called later, usually when some event occurs. For example, when adding an event listener:

```
function callback(){
  alert("click");
}
document.body.addEventListener("click", callback, true);
```

In many cases you pass the callback function as an anonymous function:

```
setTimeout(function(){alert("It's been 1 second");}, 1000);
```

The code `getListCallback = function1(obj);` will not call getListCallback with the results of function1(obj). It will store whatever `function1(obj)` returns into `getListCallback`. If function1 returns a function, then you can call that function later, like so:

```
function function1(obj){
  return function(){
    alert("getListCallback was called. obj = "+obj);
  }
}
getListCallback = function1(1);
getListCallback();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should mean that

Answer (score 0):

normally a callback function means a function which will call after current function execution finished.
This 
getListCallback = function(obj){// do something}  is like assigning this "function(obj){//....}" to a variable which can use in any place where you need to use that function.